# Как разрабатывать несколько вариантов Android приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio

В Android Studio есть проект некоего приложения. Я-бы хотел сделать несколько вариантов этого приложения с урезанным или расширенным функционалом (LITE/PRO версия). Но каждый раз для этого править основной проект не очень хочется.

Когда-то давно я видел упоминание, что в Android Studio это можно легко делать, но поиск не дал результатов. Может кто-нибудь вкратце описать как такое можно сделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331406/developing-two-versions-of-the-same-app-in-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737006/using-build-flavors-structuring-source-folders-and-build-gradle-correctly